# Cordova: java.lang.IllegalStateException: compileSdkVersion is not specified.

Tags: android, cordova

I update my cordova environment to Cordova Android 7 and got following error when `cordova build android --device --verbose`.

```
Command finished with error code 0: /usr/libexec/java_home
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/kano/Library/Android/sdk 
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home studio Subproject Path: CordovaLib Subproject Path: app Running command: /Users/kano/git_repositories/ncdc/KuiManagementSystem/app/platforms/android/gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b /Users/kano/git_repositories/ncdc/KuiManagementSystem/app/platforms/android/build.gradle
-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true -Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true 
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. 
All variants are now published. Failed to notify ProjectEvaluationListener.afterEvaluate(), 
but primary configuration failure takes precedence. 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: compileSdkVersion is not specified.
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:456)
at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:590)
at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$null$3(BasePlugin.java:555)
at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$4(BasePlugin.java:551)
at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:91)
```

And I added following parameter but same result.

```
$ cordova build android --device --verbose -- --gradleArg=-PcdvCompileSdkVersion=26
```

Does anyone know solution or workaround?

Comment: Have you found the solution yet?
I got the same issue, there is only one way to fix now is downgrading cordova android version to 6.4.0.

Comment: Hi Toan Tran.
I created new project directory and copy source code in it.
After that, I have not face this issue.

When I added Android platform in new environment, many plugin error were occured. I needed update some plugin version.

Answer (score 4):

By running following command

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --no-build
```

I had suddenly the same issue:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: compileSdkVersion is not specified.
```

Maybe your issue is different, but you should be able to track your issue down like I describe now.

---

If you read further, there is more information:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where: Script '/***/platforms/android/CordovaLib/cordova.gradle' line: 132
```

Which is following function:

```
def doExtractIntFromManifest(name) {
    def manifestFile = file(android.sourceSets.main.manifest.srcFile)
    def pattern = Pattern.compile(name + "=\"(\\d+)\"")
    def matcher = pattern.matcher(manifestFile.getText())
    matcher.find()
    println('Crashing name: ' + name) // <-- I added this line
    return new BigInteger(matcher.group(1))
}
```

I added a **println** and want to see which one crashes.
And the output was (running above command to build android):

```
Crashing name: versionCode
```

Okay, I have in my `config.xml` following set: `android-versionCode="0.0.1"`

So what's going on? The RegExp does not match the pattern anymore.

```js
var a = 'android-versionCode="1"';
var a1 = 'android-versionCode="1.0.0"';
var b = new RegExp('versionCode' + "=\"(\\d+)\"");

console.log('With Version as 1:', b.exec(a));
console.log('With Version as 1.0.0:', b.exec(a1));
```

And indeed the cordova manual page states it should be the following way:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/de/latest/config_ref/

```
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova"
  version="0.0.1"
  android-versionCode="7"
  ios-CFBundleVersion="3.3.3">
```

---

```
versionCode = PATCH + MINOR * 100 + MAJOR * 10000
CFBundleVersion = "MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH"
```

Hopefully this will help some guys since right now this issue was viewed 3000+ times.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same error as yours while using

```
cordova run android
```

I solved the problem by downgrading my android platform in project using

```
cordova platform remove android
```

then

```
cordova platform add android@6
```

for me 6 worked well

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error was coming from my own plugin and I fixed it by adding the following line to my plugin.xml file:

```
    <platform name="android">
        <preference name="android-compileSdkVersion" value="30" />
         ...
```

Comment: It stopped working again. Don't know why cordova is being bit intermittent for me.

Comment: cordova platform add android was throwing error but build was still running. Updating the plugin's gradle file to `dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.biometric:biometric:1.1.0"
}` filed my issue